# How to read/interpret Bluetooth HCI snoop log?

Tags: bluetooth, kernel, wakelock

... to continue troubleshooting to my previous question: [bluetooth - Nexus 6p - kernel wakelock - bluesleep - Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131990/nexus-6p-kernel-wakelock-bluesleep), I `Enable Bluetooth HCI snoop log` via (`Settings` -> `Developer options`) and now I have `btsnoop_hci.log`.

I'm able to open it with [Wireshark · Go Deep.](https://www.wireshark.org/), but I am confused what exactly am I looking at and/or look for? How does one determine that?

[image: Kernel Wakelock - bluesleep]